# why i cant use args as a constant expression in c++

Tags: c++, function, constexpr

I have this simple code, I want to send a two args to this function, one is "i" and the other is "n", when try to switch "i" in case of equal to 'n' I failed, because he say 'n' is not a constant expression, I read about this problem, I want to find a method to make 'n' is a constant expression.
this is the function:

```
float east_coefficient(int i, int n){
    switch(i){
        case 1:
            return 0;
            break;
        case n:
            return 0;
            break;
        default:
            return 1;
    }
}
```

and this is the main function:

```
int main(){
    int i, x;
    const int n = 5;
    x = east_coefficient(i, n);
    cout << x;
}
```

Comment: You never defined a value for `n` so it's really unclear how you plan to make it a constant expression

Comment: What do you want "n" to be?

Comment: `case`-es inside `switch` can be only compile time constant values, e.g. `1`, `2`, `3` etc, but not any variable. Even if you declare variable as constant it doesn't help. Only `constexpr` value may work in this case.

Comment: If you want to compare two variables, you have to use `if` instead of `switch`. `case` always needs a compile time constant. Simply the language is defined that way, nothing to discuss :-)

Comment: Case expressions have to be known at _compile time_ which means you cannot pass them as function arguments

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Function arguments aren't constant expressions. `n` and `i` are not initialized in your code. You can make `n` a template argument:

```
#include <iostream>

template <int n>
float east_coefficient(int i){
    switch(i){
        case 1:
            return 0;
            break;
        case n:
            return 0;
            break;
        default:
            return 1;
    }
}

int main(){
    constexpr int n = 2;
    auto x = east_coefficient<n>(42);
    std::cout << x;
}
```